# Identify Plastic Bolt Like Part on 2004 Saturn Ion 2

Tags: part-identification, saturn, plastic

I am looking to purchase a replacement for the following two parts. These parts attached the front air dam on my 2004 Saturn Ion 2 to main body of the car. It seems to be made of plastic or a similar material.
[image: First part of the object]
[image: Second part of the object]

Combined, these two parts look like this:

[image: The two parts combined]

I would prefer a part number, but any information I can use to be sure that I purchase the right part is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are just regular Clips if you take those to AutoZone they sell them all cars have them majority of all of use the same ones I don't even think they have a part number I'm sure they don't they sell them by the 10 packs I think

Comment: Agreed - I'd just call them "Plastic trim clips" - any car-parts shop should know what you mean. Take the old one with you in case there are multiple sizes...

Answer (score 1):

There are more kinds than snowflakes.  (Maybe not *that* many...)

[image]

Not sure about "Autozone", but a *good* old-fashioned autoparts store will have a display board like the one pictured above to allow you to match your old one to the proper size replacement.  They will either have them or can order them quickly.

I fnd this easier than "Hey,  Ive got a Saturn, what clip do I need?"  You may make a few extra trips with that strategy.

Best to get a few extra, in my opinion...